# Spring Cloud Config Client multiple property files retrieve from same repo

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have a requirement to retrieve the property files with environment name distinguishing those.

Config server is listening to this repo (https://github.com/tpande1/spring-cloud-config-repo/tree/master) which has : config-client-dev.properties, config-client-sbx.properties, config-client-test.properties and config-client-prod.properties

In Client Server i have the below config to read from the above github repo. How can i read these different properties with the environment specified in my Client Application?

Sample Rest Code:

```
@GetMapping("/message") //Pick message(SBX, DEV, Test, PROD) from the propertyfile from github
public String getMessage() {

    return message;

}
```

bootstrap.yml:

spring:
  profiles: dev
  application:
    name: config-client
  cloud:
    config: 
      uri:  http://localhost:1000 //Config server port
      profile: sbx, dev, test, prod

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: "*"

Comment: Added the Spring Profile to the code and application.yml but it doesn't seem to be working.

application.properties : spring.profiles.active=dev

Rest Code:
    @Profile("dev")
    @GetMapping("/message")
    public String getMessage() {

        return message;

    }

Comment: can you update your issue rather than coding in a comment?

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple active profiles in your bootstrap yaml file. In the option where you have spring.profiles.active and in your config server, you can add search patterns for each profile.

As mentioned in the below link in Pattern matching section.
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html

Comment: When i add multiple profiles the declared first profile takes precedence. For ex. profile: dev, test, lab, prod.. Dev profile always takes the precedence. Do i need to pass it as an Environment variable? My app is deployed as a container image on K8s.

Comment: Do you have similar property in all the files? If yes, do you want to use all of them or just one specific?